# Will the Yamaha SB3X-2 French horn silent brass work for a marching mellophone?

Tags: brass, mute, french-horn

I play both French horn and marching mellophone, and was wondering if the Yamaha SB3X-2 French horn silent brass pickup mute would work for the mellophone, so I don’t have to buy a second mute end.

Answer (score 1):

The Yamaha website lists the Silent Brass SBX Series, including the SB3X-2, here:
https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/winds/silent_brass/silent_brass/

There, there is a link to a [Compatibly Table](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/winds/silent_brass/silent_brass/compatibility_table.html#product-tabs) for the SBX Series.  Right up the top of this page it says:

> **The Pickup Mute is not compatible with** Piccolo Trumpets, Alto (Tenor) Horns, Baritones, Alto Trombones, Bass Trombones or **Marching Brass Instruments**.

Also, down the bottom of the page there is a *Please Note* section, the second dot point says (quite explicitly):

> **The Pickup Mute is not compatible with Marching Mellophones**, Marching French Horns, Alto (Tenor) Horns, or Baritones.

So unfortunately, it looks like the SB3X-2 *won't* work for your marching mellophone.

---

According to the Yamaha website the SBX series is actually  discontinued, but even the new SBJ series of pickup mutes apparently doesn't have a model that is compatible with marching brass instruments.